# Can I customize individuals items in a ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, customization, legend

Is it possible to make guides with different fonts, regarding a factor? I'm trying to plot my multivariate data and, in addition to the colour code, I'd like to make some of the guides bold.
Here's a reproducible example

```
  library("ggpubr")
  library("reshape2")

iris.melt <- melt(iris)

ggboxplot(data = iris.melt, x = "variable", y= "value", add = "jitter",
          add.params = list(color = "Species"), legend = "bottom") +
theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "italic")) +
guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=2), label.position = "bottom"))
```

Which produces

[image: iris boxplot]

I tried highlighting only one species

```
ggboxplot(data = iris.melt, x = "variable", y= "value", add = "jitter",
          add.params = list(color = "Species"), legend = "bottom") +
theme(legend.text = element_text(face = c("plain","italic","plain")) +
guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=2), label.position = "bottom"))
```

but "Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported."

Is there a way to customize individuals items in the legend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to set the theme components separately, but there is a workaround, which is to use expressions for labels. That way you can make any single label bold:

```r
library("ggpubr")
library("reshape2")

iris.melt <- melt(iris)

one_bold_label <- expression("Setosa", bold(paste("Versicolor")), "Virginica")

ggboxplot(data = iris.melt, x = "variable", y= "value", add = "jitter",
          add.params = list(color = "Species"), legend = "bottom") +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "italic")) +
  scale_colour_manual(labels = one_bold_label, values = c("#F8766D", "#00BA38", "#619CFF")) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = one_bold_label, values = c("white", "white", "white"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Allan! It worked well in the way that I have all the labels I wanted in bold. However, when I transpose it to my code (24 color coded species), I get double legends: a colored one with the bold labels, and a black one with plain text. I have removed the 'guides()' line but no luck. I either get the inicial legend, 2 legends or no legend.

Comment: @SaraEsteves you have to have identical labels for scale_colour_manual and scale_fill_manual so that they are merged. That's why I defined one_bold_label and applied to both scales.

Comment: @SaraEsteves or just add `+ guides(fill = "none")`, which is easier